# Is there a single word for “Seeing the Unseen”?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word which means “Seeing the Unseen”?

Imagine one needs special equipment or accessories (for example, a microscope, telescope, or periscope) to see something that otherwise is not seen with the naked eye. What is the act of “seeing the unseen” called?

Comment: Seeing it and _having missed seeing it_ seem contradictory. Do you want a word for _seeing something that is difficult to see_ or for _not seeing it_? The latter could be simply _overlooking_ it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word "unobservable" in this case.

> Whilst I could see the dog, its fleas were unobservable.

or

> He could see the river but the fish in it were unobservable.

Or how about "not discernible":

> I could see the rainbow but, through the rising fog, the colours were not discernible.

Or perhaps "not visible" or "invisible".

> From up here, I could see the leaves but the ants were not visible.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is *vision augmentation* (or the *augmentation of vision*) by technological means.

The telescope and the microscope are tools for (optical) *magnification*; a periscope transforms the image through simultaneous magnification and reflection (which may actually also apply to telescopes and microscopes).

I don't believe that kind of transformation can be described using an equally straightforward term.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Ste, there isn't a single word that directly translates to the use of technology to see something which is otherwise unseeable.

The phrase "Seeing the Unseen" does carry some context, though - it evokes the idea of the supernatural, and being able to see things which are outside of human perception.

In any case, you might be able to use **descry**:

> 2. to discover; perceive; detect. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/descry)

Answer (score 0):

As your interest is pertinent to something ocular.

My cadidates are as follows:

**1)** [**unseeable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unseeable):

> not seeable: invisible
>
> > **she gazed out over the mango trees, as if at some distant, *unseeable* tinder mangoes**

**2)** [**unnoticeable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unnoticeable):

> not worthy or likely to be noticed : not noticeable
>
> > a tiny ***unnoticeable*** black mark on elephant **OR**
> >     the reverberation will be so slight as to be ***unnoticeable***

**3)** [**inconspicuous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconspicuous)

> not readily noticeable
>
> > left an **inconspicuous** scratch on the wall

Or, if you want to sound like [Sheldon Copper](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/characters/nm1433588?ref_=tt_cl_t2) from [Big Bang Theory](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/), then try

> : Not [perceptible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptible) to [neocortex](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neocortex)

Answer (score 0):

[**Scope**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scope) (The Free Dictionary by Farlex) is the word that comes closest to your meaning and that I could find for seeing something and/or examining or evaluating something with the aid of a machine or an instrument. Though in the definition "**unseen**" word **was not seen**.

[**Scope**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scope) (The Free Dictionary by Farlex) 1. To examine or investigate, especially visually: scoped the landscape for signs of wildlife.
2. To examine using an optical instrument such as a telescope or an endoscope: scoped the stars around Orion; scoped the patient's esophagus.

Comment: You should include an authoritative dictionary definition (and link) for your selected word.

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it follows [our Help Center's guidance on how to reference work by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). ***We are not a link farm***, and a bare unattributed link does no one any good. Our reuse licence allows for plain-text reuse, and so the link would be lost if not given in actual text.

Comment: Provided link, name of source and meaning if word/words is not in common use

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly seeing the unseen: scoop.
more towards your example: insight.

Answer (score -1):

The made-to-order word for this concept is "imagination" -- i.e., the process wherein the thought becomes the image.

Comment: The question is specifically about seeing something real but normally unobservable to the naked eye.